# Show modal upon receiving push notification

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog, push-notification

I need to show a notification modal whenever a push notification is received (while the app is running).  My app has a tab bar, and I've gotten this to partially work by pushing the notification modal onto the tab bar controller.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {        
    NotificationViewController *vc = [[NotificationViewController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

This seems to fail, however, when there is already a different modal open that hides the tab bar controller.  What is the best way to make sure that the NotificationViewController *always* displays when a push notification is received, even if there is already a modal open that is hiding the tab bar controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you can do. First is to dismiss current modal controller, but it could confuse the user. The second thing would be something like that:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {      
    UIViewController* currentController = tabBarController;
    if ( [currentController modalViewController] != nil )
          currentController = [currentController modalViewController];

    NotificationViewController *vc = [[NotificationViewController alloc] init];
    [currentController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

Probably not the prettiest thing to do, as it opens another modal controller in a modal controller, but it works.